# Is the following operator well-defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, bochner-spaces

Let $u \in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open bounded set and $T>0$.

Consider the operator
$$F(u)=\begin{cases} u \quad \text{ if } \vert u(x,t) \vert \leq k \text{ for almost every } (x,t)\in \Omega \times (0,T)\\
k \quad \text{ if } u(x,t) > k \text{ for almost every } (x,t)\in \Omega \times (0,T)\\
-k \quad \text{ if } u(x,t)<-k \text{ for almost every } (x,t)\in \Omega \times (0,T)
\end{cases}$$

Is $F$ well-defined for $u \in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$?

Here is my approach:

First, I had doubts that the regularity $L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$ is not enough, since we cannot talk about pointwise values of $u$ in this case. But then again, I have tried to use the fact that since $u \in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$ then it is finite almost everywhere in $\Omega \times (0,T)$ and therefore it must satisfy one of the three cases indicated in the definition of $F$ and hence $F(u)$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I do not think it is.
And if by your observation that $u$ being square integrable implies it
being finite almost everywhere you mean that it must be bounded
(i.e., $|u(x,t)|\leq k$ for some $k$) almost everywhere,
then that is not correct.

For example,
consider the case $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}$ and $T = 1$
and choose $\Omega$ sufficiently large
(any bounded open $\Omega$ containing $[0,\pi^4/90]$ will do).
Consider the sequence $(a_n)^\infty_{n=0}$ defined inductively by
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
a_0 &= 0,
\\
a_n &= a_{n-1} + n^{-4}\quad\text{for }n > 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and let
\begin{equation*}
u(x,t) = \sum^\infty_{n=1}n 1_{[a_{n-1},a_{n})}(x).
\end{equation*}
Then
(using [some particular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function)
of the
[Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function))
we find
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
a_0 &= 0
\\
a_1 &= 0 + 1^{-4}
\\
a_2 &= 0 + 1^{-4} + 2^{-4}
\\
a_3 &= 0 + 1^{-4} + 2^{-4} + 3^{-4}
\\
&\vdots
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n &= \sum^\infty_{n=1}n^{-4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
hence $(a_n)^\infty_{n=0}$ lies in $\Omega$,
and
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega\times(0,T)}|u(x,t)|^2 dxdt
=
\sum^\infty_{n=1}n^2(a_{n+1}-a_n)
=
\sum^\infty_{n=1}n^2n^{-4}
=
\sum^\infty_{n=1}n^{-2}
=
\frac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{equation*}
So $u$ is well-defined on $\Omega\times(0,T)$
and square integrable,
but for each positive integer $k$
we have that neither $|u(x,t)|\leq k$ almost everywhere
nor $u(x,t) > k$ almost everywhere,
and $u(x,t) < -k$ for no $(x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T)$.
This leaves $F(u)$ undefined.

Comment: thanks for the example. By finite I meant that the function never reaches $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$ not bounded. Precisely i used the result stating that every Lebesgue integrable function is almost everywhere finite. I still can't get around the fact that how a function cannot satisfy $\vert u \vert<k$ almost everywhere nor $u >k$ almost everywhere nor $u<-k$ almost everywhere. Since $u$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ which is equal to  $(-\infty,-k) \bigcup [-k,k] \bigcup (k,+\infty)$. I still can't see where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe it helps to realize that the (quadratic) integral is a sum of terms, where each term is a product of the Lebesgue measure of a set ($a_n - a_{n-1}$ in the example) times the function value of $u$ (squared) on that set; though $u$ is unbounded, the (quadratic) integral is not, because the terms $a_n - a_{n-1} = n^{-4}$ decrease much harder than the associated function value $n^2$ of $u(x,t)$.

Comment: Thanks again.  I understand your point. Still the part  indicating that F is not well-defined is still ambiguous. If k>0 is a given large real; and if u>k (this includes the case where u is unbounded above), then F takes the value k. While, if u<-k (this includes the case where u is unbounded below), then F takes the value -k. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate  on why F is not well-defined. We are not looking for k satisfying the condition,  rather k is fixed at the start and depending on whether u exceeds k or is below -k the values k and -k are assigned to the function F.

Comment: Fix $k$. Then $u$ as in the example satisfies none of the three conditions in the definition of $F$. Do you perhaps mean that $F(u)$ is defined to equal $u$ at those $(x,t)$ where $|u(x,t)|\leq k$, to equal $k$ where $u(x,t)>k$ and to equal $-k$ where $u(x,t)<-k$? Because then $F$ indeed is well-defined.

Comment: Indeed that's exactly what I meant.  I should look for an alternative way to state the problem. Thank you again.